# NodeMCU doesn’t send the sensor read while powering with Vin

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, nodemcu

I have connected a NodeMCU ESP 12 with the Vin (6 volts) shared with 2 other NodeMCU. The sensors are getting power from the NodeMCU but the NodeMCU isn’t sending to the ThingSpeak cloud unless I plugged it to the PC and unplug the Vin.

Help please.[image]

Comment: What is your power supply? AA batteries? Wall adaptor?

Comment: Four of AA battery @LookAlterno

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37641/nodemcu-power-consumption-measurement-and-deepsleep

Comment: @LookAlterno I didn’t understand that topic

Comment: It looks like 4 AA batteries doesn't have enough juice to power 3 NodeMCU + sensors. Try with a battery pack, if you had one.

Comment: @LookAlterno I tried to power only one nodemcu and nothing changed

Comment: Edit your question and add a schematic (draw by hand on paper). The three NodeMCU must be connect in parallel: GND to GND, 3.3V to 3.3V.

Comment: @LookAlterno  check it now please

Comment: You must connect together all devices by their GND pin.

Comment: @LookAlterno thanks a lot dude ! Now it’s work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must connect together all devices by their GND pin.